# Edit contents of TableCell based on value in another tableCell (ComboBox) JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx, combobox, tableview, tablecell

I have a TableView (below) where I would like the user to select an item from a ComboBox which then populates the next two cells (Description and item cost) with values from a Database. In spite of much googling and headbanging, I have not figured out how to access the *specific cells* to change their values/text. Of Course invoiceClassDescription.setText() just changes the column heading which is not what I want.

I have tried `setCellSelectionEnabled(true)` and `invoiceTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedCells();` to then get index of the combobox cell and perhaps infer the index of the next two cells that way but it all got very convoluted very quickly.

[image: TableView]

Here is the code for the ClassID ComboBox:

```
invoiceClassID.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("courseID"));
    invoiceClassID.setCellFactory(column -> new TableCell<InvoiceItem, ObservableList<String>>(){
        private final ComboBox<String> combo = new ComboBox<>(courseIDs);
        {
            combo.valueProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                try {
                    Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
                    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection (DB_Updater.DB_URL,DB_Updater.USER,DB_Updater.PASS);
                    String sql = ("SELECT ClassName, TotalCost from Classes where CourseID = " + '"' + newValue + '"');
                    
                    ResultSet result = conn.createStatement().executeQuery(sql);
                    while(result.next()) {
                        
                        // set class description and cost to values in DB
                    }
                    conn.close();
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e);
                }
            });
        }
        @Override
        protected void updateItem(ObservableList<String> items, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(courseIDs, empty);
            if(empty) {
                setGraphic(null);
            } else {
                combo.setItems(courseIDs);
                setGraphic(combo);
            }
        }
    });
```

I guess my question is, how does one gain access to a specific cell to edit its contents?

Comment: You don’t access the cells. You should update the values in the item in the table’s items list.

Comment: Oh! So I just use my getters and setters? Well, that was painfully obvious!

Comment: Assuming you have everything set up correctly, yes.

Comment: I believe I do. I've been using there for all my other tables, not sure why I didn't realize that it was what I had to do for this one. Maybe not enough coffee! I'll try it after work today. Thanks.

Comment: Consider editing a selected row in a separate form rather than inline in the table. Also consider [refactoring db access to a DAO](https://edencoding.com/connect-javafx-with-sqlite/).